# grub4dos not booting on Windows Vista/7

Tags: bootloader, grub

Here are the following steps to experience this problem.

1) download grub4dos 0.4.4 here: http://download.gna.org/grub4dos/

2) copy grldr, grldr.mbr, menu.lst to C:\

3) some commands here: http://grub4dos.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Grub4dos_tutorial#Booting_GRUB_for_DOS_via_the_Windows_Vista_boot_manager

4) execute following command in cmd.exe and note the guid in the output e.g. {234325-bla-bla}:

```
bcdedit /create /d "Start GRUB4DOS" /application bootsector
```

5) then replace {id} with guid you have obtained before and execute the following ones.

```
bcdedit /set {id} device boot
bcdedit /set {id} path \grldr.mbr
bcdedit /displayorder {id} /addlast
```

6) reboot. choose "start grub4dos" on boot screen.
7) I get following error:

```
File: \grldr.mbr
Status: 0xc000000f
Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

8) do not lose that guid. use following command to delete

```
bcdedit /delete {id}
```

(9) if you lost the command, execute bcdedit and you can see grub4dos record guid here)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bcdedit /set {id} device boot
should (probably, if it's on C) be:
bcdedit /set {id} device partition=C:

this is becouse Windows 7 creates a hidden extra partition for the BCD